# iPhone: starting activity monitor for a different party app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, memory-management

I am unable to start the activity monitor on a different party app. When I choose target it says "Target failed to run: Remote exception encoutered" (see screenshot: [image: error]).

Does anyone know how to measure it? The whole point of doing this is that I am having some memory warnings and I wanted to understand what is the average memory that can be allocated by an App on an 4th+ gen iPhone without encountering warnings.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot profile 3rd party apps. As for the average memory that can be allocated: Apple does not specify any hard data. Personally, I try to stay below 15 - 20 MB. The memory needed for your app to be killed might however vary from device to device, from iOS version to iOS version and also from how many other apps are currently using memory.

Also, similar questions have been asked here before, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169935/how-much-memory-does-ios-allow-apps-to-use) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299750/how-much-memory-can-an-iphone-app-use).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am developing a game with 3 texture atlas and 2 different caf file interleaving each other and I am a bit confused on how to keep the memory down.. You said 15-20 MB, is this typical also for games?

Comment: @mm24 I don't know, I only develop utility/productivity apps. But I think it you should keep it in that range as well. As for your texture problems, I cannot help you, but I suggest you ask another question here!

Comment: thanks for your help. I accepted the question as I think answers well. I am now playing with textures and prepearing a more specific question on this. One step at the time and I hope to figure things out :). Thanks!